# In express, why do they use app and main?

Tags: firebase, express

I was following a [REST API using Express with Firebase tutorial](https://medium.com/@savinihemachandra/creating-rest-api-using-express-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-53f33f22979c) and came across this code.

```
//initialize express server
const app = express();
const main = express();

//add the path to receive request and set json as bodyParser to process the body 
main.use('/api/v1', app);
```

Why do they create both `app` and `main` and why do they pass `app` to the `'/api/v1'` route?

Comment: I suggest directing your question to the author of the tutorial to find out what they meant.  Medium does have a commenting facility.

Comment: @DougStevenson will do, thanks! although I have seen this multiple times across several different tutorials, so it seems that it is fairly common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears they are using `app` kind of like a sub-app whose routes are all prefixed with `/api/v1`.  The usual and documented way of doing something like this would be to use an Express router instead of an app object and just have one app, but the app is a router also so it will apparently work.

So, the routes on their `main` app all work at the top level such as `/about` while the routes on their `app` app all work on `/api/v1` such as `/api/v1/users`.

---

The more common way of doing this would be for the top level app to be named `app` and then use a router for the sub-app.  You would replace:

```
//initialize express server
const app = express();
const main = express();

main.use('/api/v1', app);
```

with:

```
const app = express();                // top level app
const apiRouter = express.Router();   // api router
app.use('/api/v1', apiRouter);        // hook in api router
```

Then top level routes go on the `app` object and `api` routes go on the `apiRouter` object.

---

But, this is just a more common convention.  Either way will work.